# Displaying image from within a php module

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to print the image whose location is saved in my database, I have stored the absolute location in the database and not the relative one , I browsed through a lot of question including this one 
[include a PHP result in img src tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654581/include-a-php-result-in-img-src-tag)
I tried all the options that were given to the respective asker of the question but I didn't get my output, rest everything is being displayed apart from the image, its showing no file found

Here's my code, any help will be appreciated

```
while($result=@mysql_fetch_array($resul,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $image = $result['image'];
    echo $result['company'] . " " . $result['model'] . "<br>" ;
    echo '<img src="$image" height="50" width="50" />';
}
```

I know I am using mysql functions instead of mysqli but this code is not getting live ever.

Comment: Can you provide a sample output generated by this? I'm not going to talk about the mysqli, but please, stop using @'s :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As watcher said, PHP does not do variable interpolation within single-quoted strings.

> The most important feature of double-quoted strings is the fact that variable names will be expanded.

[Read more about strings from the PHP manual.](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Therefore, when you view the HTML, you will *literally* see this:

```
<img src="$image" height="50" width="50" />
```

Your code should be:

```
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($resul,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $image = $result['image'];
    echo $result['company'] . " " . $result['model'] . "<br>";
    echo "<img src='$image' height='50' width='50'>";
}
```

Alternatively, interpolate the array value:

```
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($resul,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo $result['company'] . " " . $result['model'] . "<br>";
    echo "<img src='{$result['image']}' height='50' width='50'>";
}
```

If the filename contains spaces or other special characters, you may need to use [`rawurlencode()`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php). In this case, you **must** concatenate the string since you are calling a function that returns a `string` value:

```
echo "<img src='" . rawurlencode($result['image']) . "' height='50' width='50'>";
```

Comment: <img src="file:///c:/wamp/upload/computer/SIGN 001.jpg" height="250" width="250"> This is what I am getting when I inspect the element for the image but there is nothing being displayed, now not even the error that says no file chosen, Its just the frame for the image

Comment: Yes I am running this locally and the file does exist here, when I inspect the element for this img tag I get the absolute location and when I click on that the image is displayed in a new tab

Comment: I did it but now the code became something like this <img src="file%3A%2F%2F%2Fc%3A%2Fwamp%2Fupload%2Fcomputer%2FSIGN%20001.jpg" height="50" width="50"> but when I moved the image to the local directory of wamp i.e. in www the image is being displayed, thanks for your help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

PHP will not interpolate variables when you include them within single quotes.  For more information, see the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).